# How to retrieve a report from aws sp-api using java language and receive it using csv file type

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I use java language to call aws sp-api to retrieve the report. The file type returned is txt. How can I receive the report using csv file format?

I want to retrieve the report of csv file through sp-api.

what should i do？